# Create custom square checkbox? C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

I am a begginer so I'm asking for your help. I would like to have square checkbox with "color functions" (hover, click etc.)

This is what I did closest to what I want. Made with Bunifu UI Checkbox. (there isn't hover and sharp edges)

[Not Selected](https://ctrlv.cz/shots/2020/02/22/gzOV.png) checkboxes

[Selected](https://ctrlv.cz/shots/2020/02/22/KLW4.png) checkboxes

Sorry for my bad english. Thanks! :)

Comment: Consider adding more code and instead of links, paste images themselves (there is a button for it).

Comment: Bruh... You can't paste images, it's new account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have alternatives:

1. **Using Material Skin:** [Link in GitHub page here](https://github.com/IgnaceMaes/MaterialSkin). You have multiple controls with the Material Design pattern. The checkbox is filled with a color that you define in the code. to take into consideration, is that it needs a .NET Framework 4.6.1 or highter.
2. **Use user control**. You can place a small panel, and next to it a label. Make a Property that indicates if it is checked, another for the Label Text, another Property the Accent Color (when you check it) and the Theme Color (in case you want to use the checkbox within a form with white or black color) . And through those two colors called in the constructor of your object, and there you can generate the events